# Is it possible to write a new SpreadsheetDocument to a write-only stream?

Tags: openxml, openxml-sdk

My understanding of the OpenXML SDK is that it offers both a DOM oriented mode and a high-performance streaming SAX mode.

My goal is to write a spreadsheet directly to a network stream. Such a stream is write-only. I didn't get far at all; it didn't work.

`SpreadsheetDocument.Create` throws an exception when the stream to be written to does not support reading, writing, and seeking, which rules out streaming over a network.

Are there any options in the SDK that I'm overlooking that will enable this?

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any options in the SDK that I'm overlooking that will enable this?

No.